# How to solve Exe Bad access when changing device to ipad retina

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimage

we are developing ipad app,i am comparing two images through this code:

```
-(BOOL) compareTwoImages:(UIImage *) firstImage SecondImage:(UIImage *) secondImage
{

    int count=0;
    int match=0;
    int mismatch=0;

    //  UIColor* color = nil;
    CGImageRef inImage = [firstImage CGImage];
    CGImageRef outImage =[secondImage CGImage];

    // Create off screen bitmap context to draw the image into. Format ARGB is 4 bytes for each pixel: Alpa, Red, Green, Blue
    CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];//this method creates context

    CGContextRef cgctx1 = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:outImage];
    if (cgctx == NULL) { return NO; /* error */ }
    else if (cgctx1 == NULL) { return NO; /* error */ }

    size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}};

    // Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory
    // allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the
    // raw image data in the specified color space.

    CGContextFlush(cgctx);
    CGContextFlush(cgctx1);


    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, inImage);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx1, rect, outImage);


    CGContextFlush(cgctx);
    CGContextFlush(cgctx1);

    CGContextFlush(cgctx);
    CGContextFlush(cgctx1);



    // Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
    // context.
    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
    unsigned char* data1 = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx1);


    if ((data != NULL)&&(data1 != NULL))
    {
        //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y.
        //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.

        for( int yy=0;yy<h;yy++)
        {
            for (int xx=0; xx<w; xx++)
            {
                int offset = 4*((w*round(yy))+round(xx));
                int alpha =  data[offset];
                int alpha1 =  data1[offset];**//it is giving bad access here and finally crashing** 


                if( alpha >1 )
                {
                    count++;

                    if( alpha1 > 1 )
                    {
                        match++;

                    }

                }


                if( (alpha1 >1 )&& (alpha < 1))
                {

                    mismatch++;

                }


                //      NSLog(@"offset: %i colors: RGB A %i %i %i  %i",offset,red,green,blue,alpha);

            }
        }

    }

    // When finished, release the context
    CGContextRelease(cgctx);
    CGContextRelease(cgctx1);
    // Free image data memory for the context
    if (data) { free(data); }
    if (data1) { free(data1); }


    int matchPer =(int) (( (float) match/count)*100);
    int misMatchPer =(int) (( (float) mismatch/count)*100);


    NSLog(@"number of match px :%d  mismatch px :%d total count :%d  precntage %d mismathc per %d",match,mismatch,count,matchPer,misMatchPer);

    if(( matchPer>70)&&(misMatchPer <2000)) {//do anything}
```

its is working fine in ipad when i am comparing images through this code but creating problem when i am selecting simulator hardware >>ipad retina....

i tried to catch this bad access through intruments>>zombies but unable to catch why it is crashing...

Comment: can you let us know at where its crashing, or what is your crash logs

Answer (score 3):

*Just a thought:* Are you changing the Simulator to iPad Retina while the app is already running in Simulator? If this is the case, you don't have to worry about the crash. This happens because you are abruptly trying to stop the execution of the app (any running app quits when you change the simulator version) instead of stopping it properly from Xcode.

Comment: If you have noticed i am passing 2 image objects to this compare method(1st object is dashed line image object and 2nd object is:image of what i am drawing).my mistake was,when i converted simulator to ipad retina..now it will consider to 2x(retina)images which has double resolution in comaprision with normal image.it means it will take 2x image od dashed line(in 1st object of compare image method) and 2nd object i was not passing in 2x thats why i was crashing..

Comment: Its great that you have found the bug. Cheers!